# Confusion on firing custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a custom hook useLUGet that is intended just to be a wrapper around some axios calls.  I followed (mostly) [this repo](https://github.com/ooade/use-fetch-hook/tree/master/src), which works fine by itself because the App.js there triggers the call by an onSubmit event.  In my case I just want to load a drop down list when the page loads.  Normally I would do that with `useEffect(()=>{...}, [])` with the empty array so it fires just one, but I'm getting the dreaded "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."  The last real message logged to the console is "in useLUGet", but there are a few console log values of "0" which I also don't understand.

Here's the guts of my code.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
//import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
//import SearchForm from "./searchForm";
import AssetTypes from "./controls/AssetTypes";
import { GlobalProvider } from "./context/GlobalState";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Home
      <GlobalProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {/* <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> */}
            <Route path="/assetTypes" component={AssetTypes} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </GlobalProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AssetTypes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NativeSelect } from "@material-ui/core";

import { useLUGet } from "../services/Http";

function AssetTypes() {
  let path = `/AssetTypes?organizationId=999`;
  console.log("path: " & path);

  console.log("before useLUGet");

  const { status, data, error } = useLUGet(path);

  console.log("after useLUGet");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Asset Types</h1>

      <NativeSelect>
        {data &&
          data.map((item) => (
            <option value={item.assetTypeId}>
              {item.assetCategory} - {item.assetTypeName}
            </option>
          ))}
      </NativeSelect>
    </>
  );
}

export default AssetTypes();
```

Http.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useReducer } from "react";

const API_URL_BASE = "https://localhost:5001/api";

// Example usage:
// {status === 'idle' && (<div> Let's get started by searching for an article! </div>)}
// {status === 'error' && <div>{error}</div>}
// {status === 'fetching' && <div className="loading"></div>}
// {status === 'fetched' && (<>Do something with {data} object</>)

export const useLUGet = (path) => {
  console.log("in useLUGet");

  // const cache = useRef({});

  let url =
    API_URL_BASE & "/" & (path && path.substring(0, 1) === "/")
      ? path.substring(1)
      : path;

  console.log("url: " & url);

  const initialState = {
    status: "idle",
    error: null,
    data: [],
  };

  console.log("initial state: *** " & JSON.stringify(initialState));

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCHING":
        return { ...initialState, status: "fetching" };
      case "FETCHED":
        return { ...initialState, status: "fetched", data: action.payload };
      case "FETCH_ERROR":
        return { ...initialState, status: "error", error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelRequest = false;
    console.log("url: " & url);
    if (!url) return;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCHING" });
      //if (cache.current[url]) {
      //  const data = cache.current[url];
      //  dispatch({ type: "FETCHED", payload: data });
      //} else {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        //cache.current[url] = data;
        if (cancelRequest) return;
        dispatch({ type: "FETCHED", payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        if (cancelRequest) return;
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ERROR", payload: error.message });
      }
      //}
    };

    fetchData();

    return function cleanup() {
      cancelRequest = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return state;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are exporting the "AssetTypes" in the wrong way.
You're exporting like:

`export default AssetTypes();`

change it to:

`export default AssetTypes;`

Comment: Helpful, thank you.  At least it compiles now.  However, still not populating the data object. The JSON.Stringify line below just returns "[]".  Any additional thoughts?


console.log("before useLUGet");

  const { status, data, error } = useLUGet(path);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  console.log("after useLUGet");

Comment: @mateoc15 Your question was about the "Error: Invalid hook call." and I answered that issue. Please if my answer was the reason for your error message check my answer as the right answer and create another question for your other issues. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've created a similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270955/custom-hook-not-retrieving-data-as-expected