# Custom hook not retrieving data as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is a follow up to a related post on the same general code.  I've created a custom hook useLUGet that is intended just to be a wrapper around some fetch/axios calls.  I followed (mostly) [this repo](https://github.com/ooade/use-fetch-hook/tree/master/src), which works fine by itself because the App.js there triggers the call by an onSubmit event.  In my case I just want to load a drop down list when the page loads.  The custom hook just doesn't appear to be firing and I'm not sure how to do that without putting it a `useEffect(()=>{...}, [])` with the empty array, and that's against the magic hook rules.  I have confirmed that the API endpoint is running and has results.  The only warnings in my code are related to unused declarations.

Here's the guts of my code (updated slightly since my other related post).

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
//import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
//import SearchForm from "./searchForm";
import AssetTypes from "./controls/AssetTypes";
import { GlobalProvider } from "./context/GlobalState";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Home
      <AssetTypes></AssetTypes>
      {/* <GlobalProvider>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/assetTypes" component={AssetTypes} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </GlobalProvider> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AssetTypes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NativeSelect } from "@material-ui/core";

import { useLUGet } from "../services/Http";

function AssetTypes() {
  let path = `/AssetTypes?organizationId=999`;
  console.log("path: " & path);

  console.log("before useLUGet");
  const { status, data, error } = useLUGet(path);  // ***THIS IS THE STICKING POINT***
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("after useLUGet");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Asset Types</h1>

      <NativeSelect>
        <option>stuff</option>
        {data &&
          data.map((item) => (
            <option value={item.assetTypeId}>
              {item.assetCategory} - {item.assetTypeName}
            </option>
          ))}
      </NativeSelect>
    </>
  );
}

export default AssetTypes;
```

Http.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useReducer } from "react";

const API_URL_BASE = "https://localhost:5001/api";

// Example usage:
// {status === 'idle' && (<div> Let's get started by searching for an article! </div>)}
// {status === 'error' && <div>{error}</div>}
// {status === 'fetching' && <div className="loading"></div>}
// {status === 'fetched' && (<>Do something with {data} object</>)

export const useLUGet = (path) => {
  console.log("in useLUGet");
  console.log("path: " & path);
  console.log("API_URL_BASE: " & API_URL_BASE);
  // const cache = useRef({});

  const url =
    API_URL_BASE &
    "/" &
    (path && path.substring(0, 1) === "/" ? path.substring(1) : path);

  console.log("url: " & url);

  const initialState = {
    status: "idle",
    error: null,
    data: [],
  };

  console.log("initial state: *** " & JSON.stringify(initialState));

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCHING":
        return { ...initialState, status: "fetching" };
      case "FETCHED":
        return { ...initialState, status: "fetched", data: action.payload };
      case "FETCH_ERROR":
        return { ...initialState, status: "error", error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelRequest = false;
    console.log("url: " & url);
    if (!url) return;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCHING" });
      //if (cache.current[url]) {
      //  const data = cache.current[url];
      //  dispatch({ type: "FETCHED", payload: data });
      //} else {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        //cache.current[url] = data;
        if (cancelRequest) return;
        dispatch({ type: "FETCHED", payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        if (cancelRequest) return;
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_ERROR", payload: error.message });
      }
      //}
    };

    fetchData();

    return function cleanup() {
      cancelRequest = true;
    };
  }, [url, path]);

  return state;
};
```

Console output:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
AssetTypes.js:8 0
AssetTypes.js:10 before useLUGet
Http.js:12 in useLUGet
Http.js:13 0
Http.js:14 0
Http.js:22 0
Http.js:30 0
AssetTypes.js:13 []
AssetTypes.js:14 after useLUGet
AssetTypes.js:8 0
AssetTypes.js:10 before useLUGet
Http.js:12 in useLUGet
Http.js:13 0
Http.js:14 0
Http.js:22 0
Http.js:30 0
AssetTypes.js:13 []
AssetTypes.js:14 after useLUGet
Http.js:47 0
```

Comment: What makes you think `useEffect(()=>{...}, [])` is against the "magic hook rules"? Perhaps check out the `useEffect` [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect). The linting rules for hooks are just general recommendations to avoid stale state.

Comment: In the code above I'm getting the compile error, specifically this line in AssetTypes.js
const { status, data, error } = useLUGet(path)
Error: "./src/controls/AssetTypes.js
  Line 14:37:  React Hook "useLUGet" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"
Can the error be bypassed somehow?  And if so, I'm not sure I feel comfortable with that - convince me! :)  I'm all ears.

Comment: The `useLUGet` hook usage appears to be correct, I see no issue, and works in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-not-retrieving-data-as-expected-re8sq?file=/src/App.js), however, I do see that you are doing some odd bitwise AND (`&`) operations. Looks like you may've meant to use a `+` to do string concatenation but instead used an ampersand `&`. It seems plausible you've built a bad URL and the fetch is failing and causing *some* conditional invocation issue. Can you try reproducing your issue into a *running* codesandbox and link here?